# Is it possible to receive data contained in a JsonResult object when AJAX returns an error?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a method like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public JsonResult SomeMethod()
    object responseJson;
    try
    {
        //All good
        responseJson = new { Data = someData };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //AdditionalInfo is not returned
        responseJson = new { Error = errors, AdditionalInfo = additionalInfo };
    }

    return Json(responseJson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

If the method returns no errors I have no problem parsing responseJson, but if the response is created in the Catch, I can't access AdditionalInfo.

I can provide more details, but before I go into a long first post, I'd like to make sure I'm not missing something obvious.

Thank you!
Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies if I'm misunderstanding your question.

There's a number of approaches for handling errors in web applications but personally I've found for ASP.Net MVC applications that strictly use AJAX the easiest approach is to create two basic exception types. ServerException and ClientException. The basic difference is that ServerExceptions are errors that shouldn't ever occur and it's unlikely that the user would be able to resolve them. ClientExceptions on the other hand range anywhere from "Permission Denied" to "Invalid email format."

From there you create another class that will represent the structure of all the AJAX responses your application will produce. For example I use something like the following:

```
public class JSONMessageObject
{
    protected IList<ClientException> _ClientExceptions = null;
    protected IList<ServerException> _ServerExceptions = null;

    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public bool LoggedIn { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
    public IList<ClientException> ClientExceptions {
        get 
        {
            if(_ClientExceptions == null) _ClientExceptions = new List<ClientException>();
            return _ClientExceptions;
        }
        set 
        {
            _ClientExceptions = value;
        }
    }
    public IList<ServerException> ServerExceptions
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ServerExceptions == null) _ServerExceptions = new List<ServerException>();
            return _ServerExceptions;
        }
        set
        {
            _ServerExceptions = value;
        }
    }

    public string toJSON()
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Serialize(new
        {
            Success = Success,
            LoggedIn = LoggedIn,
            IsAdmin = IsAdmin,
            Data = Data,
            ClientExceptions = from ex in ClientExceptions
                                select new
                                {
                                    Source = ex.Source,
                                    Value = ex.Value,
                                    Message = ex.Message,
                                    Number = ex.Number
                                },
            ServerExceptions = from ex in ServerExceptions
                                select new
                                {
                                    Message = ex.Message
                                }
        });
    }
}
```

In order to get all your AJAX methods to return this structure you need to get away from using the `Json()` method directly. Instead I've created a BaseController class which all the other controllers inherit from so I can use the following call.

```
private JsonResult Message(Classes.JSONMessageObject message)
{
    return Json(message, "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Obviously it's easier to create some additional overloads to simplify some of the more common returns:

```
protected JsonResult Message()
{
    return Message(false, false, false, null);
}
protected JsonResult Message(bool success)
{
    return Message(success, false, false, null);
}
protected JsonResult Message(bool success, bool loggedIn)
{
    return Message(success, loggedIn, false, null);
}
protected JsonResult Message(bool success, bool loggedIn, bool isAdmin)
{
    return Message(success, loggedIn, isAdmin, null);
}
protected JsonResult Message(bool success, bool loggedIn, bool isAdmin, object data)
{
    return Message(new Classes.JSONMessageObject()
    {
        Success = success,
        LoggedIn = loggedIn,
        IsAdmin = isAdmin,
        Data = data
    });
}
```

So here's where the real beauty of this approach comes into play. Since your method responses have all been standardized this allows you to respond appropriately to any AJAX call without needing to know what call it was. This means that you don't have to handle exceptions in every one of your Controller methods. Just let the Global.asax Application_Error event catch them like this:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

    if (ex is Classes.ClientException)
    {
        OutputJSON(new Classes.JSONMessageObject
        {
            ClientExceptions = { (Classes.ClientException)ex }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        WriteToDatabase(ex);
    }
}
private void WriteToDatabase(Exception ex)
{
    try
    {
        int errorRecordId;

        // Save error to the database.

        OutputJSON(new Classes.JSONMessageObject()
        {
            ServerExceptions = { new Classes.ServerException("Error saved to database. Error Id: " + errorRecordId.ToString()) }
        });
    }
    catch
    {
        // Fallback...
    }
}
```

Once you've got this setup in place you can alter the `JSONMessageObject` to better suit your needs with the `AdditionalInfo` type. Or better yet, simply add it to the ClientException class.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll try this out tomorrow and will get back to you. Thank you!

Comment: Apparently Kendo UI grid kills the default AJAX error handler so my whole question was moot... I like your idea of separating client and server side errors. I can see myself using it on a different project. Thanks.